# Swift enum CLAuthorizationStatus is CLAuthorizationStatus instead of one of the cases

Tags: ios, swift, enums

This is probably just a dumb mistake, but I have a problem with my enum that I'm completely stuck at.

I have the following code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if (status == .authorizedWhenInUse) {
        print("-- authorized when in use")
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        print("--- \(String(reflecting: status))")
    }
    print("--- didChangeAuthorizationStatus = \(status)")

}
```

But the debug print statements I have in it print the following:

```
--- __C.CLAuthorizationStatus
--- didChangeAuthorizationStatus = CLAuthorizationStatus
```

**Why does the parameter `status`, which in my mind should be a case that belongs to the enum `CLAuthorizationStatus` (like `.accepted`) print `CLAuthorizationStatus`?** It makes no sense to me, and I suspect some beginner mistake but I can't find it...

In my opition, this code should behave like the following code:

```
enum TestEnum {
    case a
    case b
}

var c = TestEnum.a

func test(name e: TestEnum) {

    if e == .a {
        print("case a")
    } else {
        print("other case")
    }
    print(String(reflecting: e))
}

test(name: c)
```

Which prints, as expected

```
case a
__lldb_expr_16.TestEnum.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your fault but a current limitation of Swift on **imported** enums.

You may need to work with rawValues:

```
print(status.rawValue)
```

For example, [`3` means `CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clauthorizationstatus/authorizedalways), but as far as I know, there's no simple way to get the symbolic representation of the value.

Comment: the rawValue displays 0, which means ```.denied``` so your answer is correct. I find it very strange however that I have to do this, as I am following a swift development tutorial, in which the author does not do it and can just use the enum cases as expected... Is it possible that this is a behaviour that has changed in recent years? The tutorial is 2 years old

Comment: @charel-f, I do not remember, but `CLAuthorizationStatus` might have been just an alias of `Int32` and `print("\(status)")` might have shown the raw value without `.rawValue`. Anyway, _2 years old_ is too old in Swift world...

Comment: Thank you anyway, using rawValues has helped.

Answer (score 1):

As @OOPer said, its a limitation of Swift on imported enums.
You can create an extension to your code:

```
import CoreLocation
    
extension CLAuthorizationStatus {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        
        case .notDetermined:
            return "notDetermined"
        case .restricted:
            return "restricted"
        case .denied:
            return "denied"
        case .authorizedAlways:
            return "authorizedAlways"
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            return "authorizedWhenInUse"
        @unknown default:
            return "unknown"
        }
    }
}
```